# Ubuntu 17.10: Unclickable menus on JDownloader 2

Tags: gnome, mouse, menu, jdownloader

After upgrading from 17.04 to 17.10, and consequent switch from Unity to Gnome Shell, all the menus of JDownloader 2 became unclickable.

By "unclickable" I don't mean disabled, but that I cannot click them with the mouse.

The menu opens when I press the mouse button and closes when I release it. So I can keep the menu open by long pressing it but, even when open, the items are not clickable.

[image]

This happens with all the menus, like the usual Drop-down main menu or the right click menu.

With the right click menu, it stays open when I right click but I cannot select any entry with the mouse because the focus is on the back.

I am using OpenJDK 1.8:

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_151"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-8u151-b12-0ubuntu0.17.10.2-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
```

Comment: 17.10 defaults to Wayland. Maybe X.Org works better. You can choose it from the login screen.

Comment: @SurvivalMachine I'm already using xorg (I had issues with games using Wayland).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the **bundled JRE** is not updated automatically by JDownloader and that **was causing the problem**.

To fix it you have to either **delete/rename the `~/jd2/jre`** folder to fallback to the system JRE **or reinstall JDownloader** completely to get an updated bundled JRE.